# Capistrano 3.4.0, repo folder not deployed

Tags: deployment, capistrano, capistrano3

I am currently setting up another staging server for my PHP project. I have a working, very simple cap 3 deployment running that does nothing but use the default deployment and some tidying at the end.

For some reason, deployment to the new server does not work. It just leaves out creating a repository mirror, so everything works, except fetching the releases, because there just is no repo folder to fetch from. It just prints the folder "repo" could not be found, but continues.

Do you have an idea how to troubleshoot it or am
I missing something? I just copied the working stage file and adjusted the credentials and server data. And when setting logging to debug, I can see that it reads from remote which is the newest revision, but never even tries to set up a local mirror.

I feel like I'm missing something, but there is no deploy:setup or something that I could execute beforehand.

Cheers and thanks for your help :)

```
** Invoke mystage (first_time)
** Execute mystage
** Invoke load:defaults (first_time)
** Execute load:defaults
** Invoke deploy (first_time)
** Execute deploy
** Invoke deploy:starting (first_time)
** Execute deploy:starting
** Invoke deploy:check (first_time)
** Execute deploy:check
** Invoke git:check (first_time)
** Invoke git:wrapper (first_time)
** Execute git:wrapper
INFO [bceb88e7] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/appname/ as username@ipaddress
DEBUG [bceb88e7] Command: /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/appname/
INFO [bceb88e7] Finished in 1.370 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG Uploading /tmp/appname/git-ssh.sh 0.0%
INFO Uploading /tmp/appname/git-ssh.sh 100.0%
INFO [136ce820] Running /usr/bin/env chmod +x /tmp/appname/git-ssh.sh as username@ipaddress
DEBUG [136ce820] Command: /usr/bin/env chmod +x /tmp/appname/git-ssh.sh
INFO [136ce820] Finished in 1.229 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
** Execute git:check
INFO [108b4d67] Running /usr/bin/env git ls-remote --heads git@gitlab.domain.com:arnekolja/appname.git as username@ipaddress
DEBUG [108b4d67] Command: ( GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo GIT_SSH=/tmp/appname/git-ssh.sh /usr/bin/env git ls-remote --heads git@gitlab.domain.com:arnekolja/appname.git )
DEBUG [108b4d67]    24bd500d547c80fc6e3af59a1d3f9cd8579a07b2    refs/heads/master
INFO [108b4d67] Finished in 2.120 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
** Invoke deploy:check:directories (first_time)
** Execute deploy:check:directories
INFO [f513d3e7] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /username/www.domain.com/shared /username/www.domain.com/releases as username@ipaddress
DEBUG [f513d3e7] Command: /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /username/www.domain.com/shared /username/www.domain.com/releases
INFO [f513d3e7] Finished in 1.222 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
** Invoke deploy:check:linked_dirs (first_time)
** Execute deploy:check:linked_dirs
INFO [cbae6cba] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /username/www.domain.com/shared/fileadmin /username/www.domain.com/shared/typo3temp /username/www.domain.com/shared/uploads as username@ipaddress
DEBUG [cbae6cba] Command: /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /username/www.domain.com/shared/fileadmin /username/www.domain.com/shared/typo3temp /username/www.domain.com/shared/uploads
INFO [cbae6cba] Finished in 1.226 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
** Invoke deploy:check:make_linked_dirs (first_time)
** Execute deploy:check:make_linked_dirs
** Invoke deploy:check:linked_files (first_time)
** Execute deploy:check:linked_files
** Invoke deploy:set_previous_revision (first_time)
** Execute deploy:set_previous_revision
DEBUG [2ea98912] Running /usr/bin/env [ -f /username/www.domain.com/current/REVISION ] as username@ipaddress
DEBUG [2ea98912] Command: [ -f /username/www.domain.com/current/REVISION ]
DEBUG [2ea98912] Finished in 1.229 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [5ccb8dbf] Running /usr/bin/env cat /username/www.domain.com/current/REVISION 2>/dev/null as username@ipaddress
DEBUG [5ccb8dbf] Command: /usr/bin/env cat /username/www.domain.com/current/REVISION 2>/dev/null
DEBUG [5ccb8dbf] Finished in 1.229 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
** Invoke deploy:started (first_time)
** Execute deploy:started
** Invoke deploy:updating (first_time)
** Invoke deploy:new_release_path (first_time)
** Execute deploy:new_release_path
** Execute deploy:updating
** Invoke git:create_release (first_time)
** Invoke git:update (first_time)
** Invoke git:clone (first_time)
** Invoke git:wrapper 
** Execute git:clone
DEBUG [ed6bb904] Running /usr/bin/env [ -f /username/www.domain.com/repo/HEAD ] as username@ipaddress
DEBUG [ed6bb904] Command: [ -f /username/www.domain.com/repo/HEAD ]
DEBUG [ed6bb904] Finished in 1.219 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO The repository mirror is at /username/www.domain.com/repo
** Execute git:update
DEBUG [a62aadce] Running /usr/bin/env if test ! -d /username/www.domain.com/repo; then echo "Directory does not exist '/username/www.domain.com/repo'" 1>&2; false; fi as username@ipaddress
DEBUG [a62aadce] Command: if test ! -d /username/www.domain.com/repo; then echo "Directory does not exist '/username/www.domain.com/repo'" 1>&2; false; fi
DEBUG [a62aadce]    Directory does not exist '/username/www.domain.com/repo'
DEBUG [a62aadce] Finished in 1.225 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [24f065b3] Running /usr/bin/env git remote update as username@ipaddress
DEBUG [24f065b3] Command: cd /username/www.domain.com/repo && ( GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo GIT_SSH=/tmp/appname/git-ssh.sh /usr/bin/env git remote update )
DEBUG [24f065b3]    shell: line 0: cd: /username/www.domain.com/repo: No such file or directory
INFO [24f065b3] Finished in 1.288 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
** Execute git:create_release
DEBUG [bbc9e0f5] Running /usr/bin/env if test ! -d /username/www.domain.com/repo; then echo "Directory does not exist '/username/www.domain.com/repo'" 1>&2; false; fi as username@ipaddress
DEBUG [bbc9e0f5] Command: if test ! -d /username/www.domain.com/repo; then echo "Directory does not exist '/username/www.domain.com/repo'" 1>&2; false; fi
DEBUG [bbc9e0f5]    Directory does not exist '/username/www.domain.com/repo'
DEBUG [bbc9e0f5] Finished in 1.471 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [c79a9ebf] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /username/www.domain.com/releases/20150824184523 as username@ipaddress
DEBUG [c79a9ebf] Command: cd /username/www.domain.com/repo && ( GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo GIT_SSH=/tmp/appname/git-ssh.sh /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /username/www.domain.com/releases/20150824184523 )
DEBUG [c79a9ebf]    shell: line 0: cd: /username/www.domain.com/repo: No such file or directory
INFO [c79a9ebf] Finished in 1.226 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [1761463a] Running /usr/bin/env git archive master | tar -x -f - -C /username/www.domain.com/releases/20150824184523 as username@ipaddress
DEBUG [1761463a] Command: cd /username/www.domain.com/repo && ( GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo GIT_SSH=/tmp/appname/git-ssh.sh /usr/bin/env git archive master | tar -x -f - -C /username/www.domain.com/releases/20150824184523 )
DEBUG [1761463a]    shell: line 0: cd: /username/www.domain.com/repo: No such file or directory
INFO [1761463a] Finished in 1.111 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
** Invoke deploy:set_current_revision (first_time)
** Execute deploy:set_current_revision
** Invoke git:set_current_revision (first_time)
** Execute git:set_current_revision
DEBUG [75e5e6d4] Running /usr/bin/env if test ! -d /username/www.domain.com/repo; then echo "Directory does not exist '/username/www.domain.com/repo'" 1>&2; false; fi as username@ipaddress
DEBUG [75e5e6d4] Command: if test ! -d /username/www.domain.com/repo; then echo "Directory does not exist '/username/www.domain.com/repo'" 1>&2; false; fi
DEBUG [75e5e6d4]    Directory does not exist '/username/www.domain.com/repo'
DEBUG [75e5e6d4] Finished in 1.342 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [591e17b8] Running /usr/bin/env git rev-list --max-count=1 --abbrev-commit master as username@ipaddress
DEBUG [591e17b8] Command: cd /username/www.domain.com/repo && ( GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo GIT_SSH=/tmp/appname/git-ssh.sh /usr/bin/env git rev-list --max-count=1 --abbrev-commit master )
DEBUG [591e17b8]    shell: line 0: cd: /username/www.domain.com/repo: No such file or directory
DEBUG [591e17b8] Finished in 1.227 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [af0b741e] Running /usr/bin/env if test ! -d /username/www.domain.com/releases/20150824184523; then echo "Directory does not exist '/username/www.domain.com/releases/20150824184523'" 1>&2; false; fi as username@ipaddress
DEBUG [af0b741e] Command: if test ! -d /username/www.domain.com/releases/20150824184523; then echo "Directory does not exist '/username/www.domain.com/releases/20150824184523'" 1>&2; false; fi
DEBUG [af0b741e]    Directory does not exist '/username/www.domain.com/releases/20150824184523'
DEBUG [af0b741e] Finished in 1.226 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [1a7a9f89] Running /usr/bin/env echo "" >> REVISION as username@ipaddress
DEBUG [1a7a9f89] Command: cd /username/www.domain.com/releases/20150824184523 && /usr/bin/env echo "" >> REVISION
DEBUG [1a7a9f89]    shell: line 0: cd: /username/www.domain.com/releases/20150824184523: No such file or directory
INFO [1a7a9f89] Finished in 1.275 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
** Invoke deploy:symlink:shared (first_time)
** Execute deploy:symlink:shared
** Invoke deploy:symlink:linked_files (first_time)
** Execute deploy:symlink:linked_files
** Invoke deploy:symlink:linked_dirs (first_time)
** Execute deploy:symlink:linked_dirs
INFO [9631b1e2] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /username/www.domain.com/releases/20150824184523 /username/www.domain.com/releases/20150824184523 /username/www.domain.com/releases/20150824184523 as username@ipaddress
DEBUG [9631b1e2] Command: /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /username/www.domain.com/releases/20150824184523 /username/www.domain.com/releases/20150824184523 /username/www.domain.com/releases/20150824184523
INFO [9631b1e2] Finished in 1.183 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [128c1b78] Running /usr/bin/env [ -L /username/www.domain.com/releases/20150824184523/fileadmin ] as username@ipaddress
DEBUG [128c1b78] Command: [ -L /username/www.domain.com/releases/20150824184523/fileadmin ]
DEBUG [128c1b78] Finished in 1.221 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [647f61de] Running /usr/bin/env [ -L /username/www.domain.com/releases/20150824184523/typo3temp ] as username@ipaddress
DEBUG [647f61de] Command: [ -L /username/www.domain.com/releases/20150824184523/typo3temp ]
DEBUG [647f61de] Finished in 1.226 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG [eda585b8] Running /usr/bin/env [ -L /username/www.domain.com/releases/20150824184523/uploads ] as username@ipaddress
DEBUG [eda585b8] Command: [ -L /username/www.domain.com/releases/20150824184523/uploads ]
DEBUG [eda585b8] Finished in 1.226 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
** Invoke deploy:updated (first_time)
** Execute deploy:updated
** Invoke deploy:publishing (first_time)
** Execute deploy:publishing
** Invoke deploy:symlink:release (first_time)
** Execute deploy:symlink:release
INFO [3216ea2a] Running /usr/bin/env ln -s /username/www.domain.com/releases/20150824184523 /username/www.domain.com/releases/current as username@ipaddress
DEBUG [3216ea2a] Command: /usr/bin/env ln -s /username/www.domain.com/releases/20150824184523 /username/www.domain.com/releases/current
INFO [3216ea2a] Finished in 1.224 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [4dffab11] Running /usr/bin/env mv /username/www.domain.com/releases/current /username/www.domain.com as username@ipaddress
DEBUG [4dffab11] Command: /usr/bin/env mv /username/www.domain.com/releases/current /username/www.domain.com
INFO [4dffab11] Finished in 1.105 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
** Invoke deploy:published (first_time)
** Execute deploy:published
** Invoke deploy:finishing (first_time)
** Execute deploy:finishing
** Invoke deploy:cleanup (first_time)
** Execute deploy:cleanup
DEBUG [cff18115] Running /usr/bin/env ls -xtr /username/www.domain.com/releases as username@ipaddress
DEBUG [cff18115] Command: /usr/bin/env ls -xtr /username/www.domain.com/releases
DEBUG [cff18115]    20150824180444  20150824182922  20150824183624  20150824184523
DEBUG [cff18115] Finished in 1.347 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO Keeping 3 of 4 deployed releases on ipaddress
INFO [efc5b837] Running /usr/bin/env rm -rf /username/www.domain.com/releases/20150824180444 as username@ipaddress
DEBUG [efc5b837] Command: /usr/bin/env rm -rf /username/www.domain.com/releases/20150824180444
INFO [efc5b837] Finished in 1.123 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
** Invoke deploy:notify (first_time)
** Execute deploy:notify
** Invoke deploy:finished (first_time)
** Execute deploy:finished
** Invoke deploy:log_revision (first_time)
** Execute deploy:log_revision
DEBUG [c571276a] Running /usr/bin/env if test ! -d /username/www.domain.com/releases; then echo "Directory does not exist '/username/www.domain.com/releases'" 1>&2; false; fi as username@ipaddress
DEBUG [c571276a] Command: if test ! -d /username/www.domain.com/releases; then echo "Directory does not exist '/username/www.domain.com/releases'" 1>&2; false; fi
DEBUG [c571276a] Finished in 1.372 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [964a1750] Running /usr/bin/env echo "Branch master (at ) deployed as release 20150824184523 by arne" >> /username/www.domain.com/revisions.log as username@ipaddress
DEBUG [964a1750] Command: echo "Branch master (at ) deployed as release 20150824184523 by arne" >> /username/www.domain.com/revisions.log
INFO [964a1750] Finished in 1.096 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
Arne-Koljas-MacBook-Air:appname.local arne$
```

deploy.rb (sanitized my custom hooks out of the debug output above)

```
lock '3.4.0'
set :application, 'appname'
set :repo_url, 'git@gitlab.domain.com:arnekolja/appname.git'
set :scm, :git
set :log_level, :debug
set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []).push('fileadmin', 'typo3temp', 'uploads')
set :keep_releases, 3

namespace :deploy do

  after :restart, :clear_cache do
    on roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
      # nothing here yet
    end
  end

  after :finishing, :notify do
    on roles(:web) do
      if test("[ -d #{shared_path}/typo3temp/DynCss ]")
        info "Clearning cached (S)CSS file at #{shared_path}/typo3temp/DynCss/* …"
        execute "rm -rf #{shared_path}/typo3temp/DynCss/*"
      else
        info "No (S)CSS file to remove at #{shared_path}/typo3temp/DynCss/*."
      end

      if test("[ -d #{shared_path}/typo3temp/Cache ]")
        info "Clearning TYPO3 cache at #{shared_path}/typo3temp/Cache/* …"
        execute "rm -rf #{shared_path}/typo3temp/Cache/*"
      else
        info "No TYPO3 cache folder at #{shared_path}/typo3temp/Cache/* (yet?), not clearing it."
      end
    end
  end

  before :starting, :mysqlbackup

  desc "Backup MySQL Database"
  task :mysqlbackup do
    on roles(:web) do
      execute "mysqldump --socket=/tmp/mysql5.sock -u#{fetch(:db_username)} -p#{fetch(:db_password)} #{fetch(:db_database)} > #{shared_path}/backups/#{release_timestamp}.sql"
      execute "gzip #{shared_path}/backups/#{release_timestamp}.sql"
    end
  end

end
```

mystage.rb:

```
server 'ipaddress', user: 'user', roles: %w{db web}, password: 'password'
set :deploy_to, '/user/www.domain.com'
# set :pty, true
set :db_database, "db"
set :db_username, "user"
set :db_password, "pass"
```

Comment: Could you post a sanitized debug output?

Comment: I appended the sanitized output.

Comment: Thanks. Could you post your deploy.rb? Also, exactly what command are you using to run this?

Comment: added all you might need, sorry for not doing this in the first place :-)

Comment: Thanks. You run cap env deploy?

Comment: correct. first run/release on this server, only initial "setup" via cap mystage deploy, as I don't think I need more to init it.

Comment: I'm not sure this will help, but could you try adding "app" to the list of roles for the server?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87890/discussion-between-arnekolja-and-will-in-wi).